# Integral with Logs

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I have a two integrals mathematica won't solve and I'm not sure how to solve them although I'm certain they are solvable.

The first one is:

$\int_{0}^\pi \log\left(A-B\cos\theta\right)\left(A+B\cos\theta\right)\sin^2\theta d\theta$

The second one is

$\int_{0}^\pi \frac{\log\left(A-B\cos\theta\right)}{\left(A-B\cos\theta\right)}\sin^2\theta d\theta$

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram alpha?

Comment: Maple can solve the first one.

Comment: I think you'll want to assume $A > |B|$ to avoid taking the log of a negative number.

Comment: Robert, the suggestion was good, and Mathematica  now handles both integrals with this assumption. Thank you.

Comment: right, I will but let me get it cleaned up a little :)